# How to add encoder/decoder layers to PyTorch transformers after inference?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, overriding, transformer-model

I have a PyTorch encode-decoder transformer: I want to save the model and then load in the weights, except in an upscaled model. So, for example, I want to train a model on 3 encoder layers and 3 decoder layers, save the parameters. Then, I want to load in all the parameters, but add another random encoder and decoder layer at the end. Then, I want to freeze all the parameters during inference except for the new layers. These are essentially adapter layers, but I want to do them as blocks instead.

Class code:

```
class Seq2SeqTransformer(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self,
              num_encoder_layers: int,
              num_decoder_layers: int,
              emb_size: int,
              nhead: int,
              src_vocab_size: int,
              tgt_vocab_size: int,
              dim_feedforward: int = 512,
              dropout: float = 0.1):
    super(Seq2SeqTransformer, self).__init__()
    self.transformer = Transformer(d_model=emb_size,
                                    nhead=nhead,
                                    num_encoder_layers=num_encoder_layers,
                                    num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers,
                                    dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward,
                                    dropout=dropout)
    self.generator = nn.Linear(emb_size, tgt_vocab_size)
    self.src_tok_emb = TokenEmbedding(src_vocab_size, emb_size)
    self.tgt_tok_emb = TokenEmbedding(tgt_vocab_size, emb_size)
    self.positional_encoding = PositionalEncoding(emb_size, dropout=dropout)

  def forward(self,
              src: Tensor,
              trg: Tensor,
              src_mask: Tensor,
              tgt_mask: Tensor,
              src_padding_mask: Tensor,
              tgt_padding_mask: Tensor,
              memory_key_padding_mask: Tensor):
      src_emb = self.positional_encoding(self.src_tok_emb(src))
      tgt_emb = self.positional_encoding(self.tgt_tok_emb(trg))
      outs = self.transformer(src_emb, tgt_emb, src_mask, tgt_mask, None,
                              src_padding_mask, tgt_padding_mask, memory_key_padding_mask)
      return self.generator(outs)

  def encode(self, src: Tensor, src_mask: Tensor):
      return self.transformer.encoder(self.positional_encoding(
                          self.src_tok_emb(src)), src_mask)

  def decode(self, tgt: Tensor, memory: Tensor, tgt_mask: Tensor):
      return self.transformer.decoder(self.positional_encoding(
                        self.tgt_tok_emb(tgt)), memory,
                        tgt_mask)
```